# All possible binary matrices with some properties

Tags: matrices, algorithms, python, sagemath

I need to generate all possible $4 \times 4$ symmetric binary matrices with $0$s on its main diagonal and in which $1$ appears $6$ times. Examples:

```
[[0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1],
 [0,1,0,1],
 [0,1,1,0]] 

[[0,1,1,0],
 [1,0,1,0],
 [1,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0]]  

[[0,1,0,1],
 [1,0,0,1],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [1,1,0,0]]
```

How could I do that in Python?

Comment: The upper triangle has $3$ ones, so you just have to generate the $3-$subsets of a $6-$element set.  Look at `itertools.combinations`

Comment: Note: also asked as [StackOverflow question 51146949](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51146949).

Comment: Note: [posting a question on two StackExchange sites is discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script that does it:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

triangle = [(i,j) for i in range(4) for j in range (i+1,4)]

def matrices():
    for t in combinations(triangle,3):
        m = np.zeros((4,4))
        for c in t:
            m[c]=1
        yield m+m.transpose()

M = [m for m in matrices()]
print(M[-1]) # print the last matrix in the list
print(M[0])  # print the first matrix in the list
print(M[-1][-1,:]) #print the last row of the last matrix     
for m in matrices():
    print(m)
```

Comment: yes,, thanks, d, How could I go through each of these matrices?

Comment: Just like I printed them at the bottom.

Comment: yes, but, with for, print all the matrices. How could i print just 1 by 1,, i thinks that m[1], but just print one row of last matrix

Comment: thanks, I'm just starting with sage, I found it interesting but I still need to learn a lot.

Comment: You want a list of the matrices instead of a generator, it seems like.  So, you can just make a list out of the generator: `M=[m for m in matrices()]`  I added some examples of how to use the list.  Note that if you want  row $k$ of the matrix $A$ the numpy syntax is `A[k,:]`

Comment: @MathNewC I don't know anything about sage.  This is just straight python.  I don't know whether sage uses numpy, but I tend to doubt it.  I just realized that I'd never saved my edit.  I hope things are clearer now.  Sorry